# tensorflow.js bodypix model not working and not giving any error

Tags: javascript, image, image-segmentation, tensorflow.js, bodypix

I am creating a simple body segmenting html [following this](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2019/11/updated-bodypix-2.html)

I have tried:

```
  <body> 
       <!-- Load TensorFlow.js --> 
       <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.13.3"></script> 
       <!-- Load BodyPix -->
       <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/body-pix"></script> 
           bodypix.load().then(function(net) {
               // BodyPix model loaded
           });
       </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

With this script:

```
// load the BodyPix model from a checkpoint
const net = await bodyPix.load();

// arguments for estimating person segmentation.
const outputStride = 16;
const segmentationThreshold = 0.5;

const personSegmentation = await net.estimatePersonSegmentation(imageElement, outputStride, segmentationThreshold);
```

It works fine giving no error, but the problem is that it is not detecting person from even a simple image. I have tried this link for a demo, using an image given with the [source code](https://glitch.com/%7Ecolor-pop-effect)
but even there it is masking the whole image not detecting any body returning an uint8clamped array full of only zeroes ***the same model works in my mobile.***
Is it a problem with my pc.
It is i7 2600 3.7ghz

***NOTE- I have no gpu***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Error

Actually the error is that by default tensorflow uses webGL backend. If you dont have a GPU then it will crash

## The Solution

<sup>note- this solution is for node js but you can use similar concept with script tags also</sup>

To solve the problem you have to at first import @tensorflow/tfjs or @tensorflow/tfjs-core or @tensorflow/tfjs-node and then set its backend as cpu (or tensorflow if you are using @tensorflow/tfjs-node)
Refer to the below script

```
//main.js file, works well with webpack
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs-core'
import * as bodypix from '@tensorflow-models/body-pix'

tf.setBackend('cpu')

//now you can load bodypix or any model
```

For documentation refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/platform_environment)